# Eigenvalues of hamiltonian

Tags: quantum-mechanics, homework-and-exercises, hamiltonian, eigenvalue

> Q: THe hamiltonian which describes the motion of a particle in an one dimensional potential V(x) is $H_0=\frac{p^2}{2m}+V(x)$ , where $p=-i\hbar \frac{d}{dx}$ is the momentum operator.
>   $E_n^0$ , $n=1,2,3$   are the eigenvalues of the operator $H_0$. Now consider a new hamiltonian $H=H_0 + l\frac{p}{m}$ . Find the eigenvalues of $H$ if you know $l$ and $E_n^0$ .

My progress is: $H=H_0 + l\frac{p}{m}= \frac{p^2}{2m}+V(x)+l\frac{p}{m}=\frac{(p+l)^2}{2m}+V(x)-\frac{l^2}{2m}$ , but the term $(p+l)^2$ confuses me.

Any help appreciated.

Comment: Look for a unitary operator such that $U p U^\dagger = p+ l$ and that commutes with $V(x)$...

Comment: As it stands, there really isn't a question here (kinda a necessity on a Q&A site such as this one). This could be easily fixed if you expand on what you don't understand about the $(p+l)^2$ term.

Comment: The problem is clear, I do not understand why someone voted to close this question. The OP already made some (correct) efforts to determine the spectrum of $H$, as clearly written. The only remaining step after my suggestion and the more complete answer by Rod is now observing that unitarily equivalent operators have the same spectrum and that the spectrum of $A+ aI$ is $\sigma(A) + a$...

Comment: @ValterMoretti Could you please refer to some books or internet articles where this method of approach is mentioned.

Comment: @workaholic Sorry, I cannot suggest any precise reference. It not an approach or a method, just the application of elementary facts of spectral theory...

Comment: @ValterMoretti Thank you. Spectral theory is enough.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let the operator $q$ be defined by $f \mapsto \exp\left(i\,\frac{l}{\hbar}\,x\right)\,f$ then you should be able to prove to yourself the identity:

$$p\,q\,f = q\,(p+l)\,f\tag{1}$$

for any vector (*i.e.* function) f. (This is just a variation on finding an integrating factor to transform $\mathrm{d}_x\,f + i\frac{l}{\hbar} f$ into the derivative of a product - if you're wondering where I pulled this from). Equivalently:

$$q^\dagger\,p\,q = p+l$$

Now, our operator $q$, being a simple multiplication by $\exp\left(i\,\frac{l}{\hbar}\,x\right)$, naturally commutes with the potential multiplication operator $f\mapsto V\,f$.  Hence, naturally, $q^\dagger\,V\,q = V$. So our whole Hamiltonian can now be written:

$$H = q^\dagger\,\left(H_0 - \frac{l^2}{m}\right)\,q$$

This should help you a great deal.